# Difference between variable.functionName and variable["functionName"]

Tags: lua, lua-table

I know that you can get variables and call functions both by using the name directly

```
variable.functionName
```

or using the name as a string

```
variable["functionName"] or variable[functionNameString]
```

Now my question is:
Is there any resulting difference in these different ways or are they completely interchangeable?

I am mostly interested about performance here, but any enlightenment is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PUC-Rio Lua 5.1 byte code for

```
print(variable.functionName)
print(variable["functionName"])
print(variable[functionNameString])
```

is

```
main <var.lua:0,0> (14 instructions, 56 bytes at 0xafe530)
0+ params, 3 slots, 0 upvalues, 0 locals, 4 constants, 0 functions
    1   [1] GETGLOBAL   0 -1    ; print
    2   [1] GETGLOBAL   1 -2    ; variable
    3   [1] GETTABLE    1 1 -3  ; "functionName"
    4   [1] CALL        0 2 1
    5   [2] GETGLOBAL   0 -1    ; print
    6   [2] GETGLOBAL   1 -2    ; variable
    7   [2] GETTABLE    1 1 -3  ; "functionName"
    8   [2] CALL        0 2 1
    9   [3] GETGLOBAL   0 -1    ; print
    10  [3] GETGLOBAL   1 -2    ; variable
    11  [3] GETGLOBAL   2 -4    ; functionNameString
    12  [3] GETTABLE    1 1 2
    13  [3] CALL        0 2 1
    14  [3] RETURN      0 1
```

As you can see the first two lines generate exactly the same byte code (and thus take the same amount of time), while the third line has an additional (global) variable access.

The first line only works since `"functionName"` is a valid Lua identifier and not a reserved word. Lines 2 and 3 don't have restrictions about the format of the string key.

Comment: That listing is output by `luac -l -p`.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same. From [the manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1):

> ...  To represent records, Lua uses the field name as an index. The language supports this representation by providing `a.name` as syntactic sugar for `a["name"]`.